# Get full path of product from Win32_Products

Tags: c#, registry

I'm currently using the following query to get a list of installed products:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product");
```

From this, I can get the `InstallLocation` of the products, but I want to be able to go (at least) one level deeper. It doesn't necessarily have to be the entire path to the executable -- it really just needs to be one directory deeper. The entire path would obviously work too, though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible. Products exists with more than one executable, so such a feature would be ambiguous at best.

## Edit, thoughts on your comments:

If you are searching for installations of your own product, perhaps you could:

1. Check to see if your product is installed using the IdentifyingNumber and your WMI query.
2. If you got any results on that, find the InstallLocation from WMI, then search for your products executable below that directory (easier, because you will know the name or name(s) of executables to search for).

Comment: Well, maybe you can help on the "big picture" question then. Basically, given a directory, I need to find any MSI-installed products within that directory. I just want to be able to check if there is an instance of my product installed within a directory before I install something over it. Can't use third party tools, either.

Comment: Finding a product's location (or the location of its key files) by its ProductID would work, too.

Comment: I updated my answer with some thoughts on that, not sure if it will help you to a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont think that'll work. Here's the issue: Let's say the InstallLocation is "C:\MyCompany\MyProductName". That folder may contain 3 more folders, "Instance1","Instance2","Instance3", each of which contains an installation of my product. So, all of them have the same InstallLocation. I want to be able to check to see if a product is installed in, for example, "C:\MyCompany\MyProductName\Instance1" and, if so, uninstall it. To uninstall it, in my context at least, I need its ProductID. So somehow I need to find a relationship between productID and file location.

Comment: Being able to find the productID of a product given its installer's path would probably work too

Comment: ^on second thought, no it wouldnt. It's gonna have to be the path to one of the files that was installed. Sorry for cluttering your inbox, lol.